# Segmentation Fault only happens when not printing to screen

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to code the Forward-Difference Method to solve a heat equation, however my code always gets a Segmentation Fault during the 13th iteration. So I went to debug by sticking some printf's into the loop and checking the values of some variables.  Once I stick in the printf's, my loop successfully continues past the point where it Faulted before. However, if I just comment out those printf's, the code will Fault again... Anyone have an idea of why this could be?

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//          Math 448 Assignment 5 Gauss-Seidel
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

#define I 9
#define J 100
#define M 10


double w[M][J] = {0};
double v[M] = {0};
double K = 0.005;
double H = 0.1;

// J is time, t
// I is distance, x

int main(void){

    // First build up t=0
    int i,j;
    double lambda;
    double t = 0;

        printf("k=%lf\th=%lf\n", K, H);
    lambda = (0.5)*(double)K/(H*H);

    for(i=0;i<=M-1;i++){
        if(i<=5)
        {
            w[i][0] = i*H;
        }else{
            w[i][0] = (double)(1-i*H);
        }
    }

    printf("lam=%lf\n",lambda);

    for(j=1;j<=J;j++){
        v[0] = 0;
        v[I-1] = 0;

        for(i=1;i<=M-1;i++){
            if(t>=0.06){
                            // THESE ARE THE PRINTS THAT CAUSE IT TO WORK
                //printf("i=%d\n1) %lf\n2) %lf\n3) %lf\n",i, w[i-1][j-1], w[i][j-1], w[i+1][j-1]);
                //getchar();
            }
            v[i] = lambda*w[i-1][j-1] + (1-2*lambda)*w[i][j-1] + lambda*w[i+1][j-1];

        }

        t = j*K;
        printf("t=%.4lf\t",t);
        for(i=0;i<M;i++){
            printf("%.4lf\t", v[i]);
        }

        for(i=1;i<M-1;i++){
            w[i][j] = v[i];
        }

        printf("\n");

    }


    /*
            //Psuedocode
        for j=1 to N
            v0 = 0
            vm = 0
            for i=1 to m-1
                vi = LAM*Wi-1 + (1-2LAM)*Wi + LAM*Wi+1
                end for
            t = i*k
            output(v0, v1, v2...)
        end for
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Memory corruption. Have you tried running through valgrind?

Comment: It looks this is going out of bound `w[i][j] = v[i];` since `j` can go up to the value `J`

Comment: w[i+1] is out of bounds, when i = M-1, line 54, says cppcheck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right here:

```
for(j=1;j<=J;j++)
```

You are iterating `j` from `0` to `J`, but the array can be indexed from `0` to `J-1`.

Also, based on Lol4t0's comment, here:

`w[i+1][j-1];`

for `i = M`.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access a slot out of array bounds for `j == J`. The indices are in the `0...J-1` range.